# declaring variable with number is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to show the variable that i declared in js just to initiate it with a number and show his value 'world' but it shows the name of variablewith number i dont know where is the error in syntax
he gives me as result Hello name0!

```js
$scope.n=0;
$scope['name'+$scope.n] = 'World';
```

```html
<p>Hello {{'name'+n}}!</p>
```

Comment: consider using an array for this.

Comment: I faced this in the past. Try defining something like: `$scope.All_Variables = {n:"",name0:""}` and replace `$scope` by `$scope.All_Variables` in your code.

Comment: Wait!!! The error in the snippet states that `$scope` is undefined. Are you using it within a controller? Was `$scope` properly injected?

Comment: The snippet doesn't include Angular, so its error messages aren't going to be relevant to the question.

Comment: it doesnt give qn error it gives hello name0

Answer (score 1):

Create another scope object to add the variable property to so you can reference that object in the view and use `[]` notation for the variable property name there

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.n=0;
$scope.data['name'+$scope.n] = 'World';
```

View

```
<p>Hello {{data['name'+n]}}!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to access the context object (`$scope`) using the identifier `this`:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.n=0;
    $scope['name'+$scope.n] = 'World';
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <p>Hello {{this['name'+n]}}!</p>
</body>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expression Context](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#context).